# CALayer won't work

Tags: iphone, ios, colors, calayer, rounded-corners

I keep getting an error on this line of code:

```
[round setCornerRadius:10.0f];
```

Here is what I'm doing around it.

```
CALayer *round = [_logInBtn layer];
[round setMasksToBounds:YES];
[round setCornerRadius:10.0f];// here is where the error is at
[round setBorderWidth:1.0];
[round setBorderColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
```

`_loginBtn` is just a `UIButton`;

It's saying this:`EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x4a59)`

And this is in the log: `<Error>: CGGradientCreateWithColors: invalid color space.`

The weird thing is that it only gives me this error about every other time I try to build.  What can I do to fix this bug?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
CALayer *imageBaseMaskLayer = [CALayer layer];
imageBaseMaskLayer  setMaskimageBasedMaskLayer];
```

Answer (score 0):

The layer wants a color in the RGB space not the BW space. So use a different technique:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5] CGColor]
```

That is, create a RGB color with similar values to approximate gray.